# For what nonnegative measures $\mu$ does $\mu*e^{-|\cdot|}\in L^{\infty}$?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to characterize all measures on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \: (\mu*f)(x)<+\infty,
$$

where $f(x)$ is some specific integrable functions, such as $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$, and "$*$" denotes the convolution. This suggests that find whether the measures do not have any growing tails (hence the title of the post).

The space of Radon measures is the dual of continuous functions with compact support. It may have arbitrary large growing tails. For example, $\mu(d x)=e^{|x|}d x$ and $\mu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|n|\: \delta_n$.

Measures which fall in our class include the following examples:

1. Absolutely continuous measures with bounded density function, such as the Lebesgue measure.
2. $\mu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta_n(x).$

Does any one come across this kind of measures? Is this set of measures studied somewhere?

Thanks for any references and remarks!

Comment: What is the norm (topology) on this space (of continuous integrable functions)? There doesn't seem to be an obvious candidate.

Comment: Thanks Christian Remling. Shall one use the $L^1$ norm?

Comment: @Anand, the space is not Banach with that norm. Do you want that?

Comment: Then your space is a dense subspace of $L^1$, so continuous functionals have unique extensions to elements of $(L^1)^*=L^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks Joonas Limavirta, it doesn't matter if the resulting space is a dual of a Banach space or not. I am wondering if there are any references for this set of measures? Are there any people ever interested in this space? It comes natural in some research.

Comment: Thanks Cristian Remling. But $L^{\infty}$ doesn't include "real" measures, right? See my example. :-)

Comment: Anand, integrating against your $\mu$ is not continuous in the $L^1$ norm, there are continuous functions $f$ of arbitrarily small $L^1$ norm for which $\int fd\mu=1$ (or $\infty$). Also I don't understand what is your space of measures. Both your examples are Radon measures, is this your space?

Comment: Thanks Pablo Shmerkin, I think my example is not a good one. You are absolutely right! Do you know a way to characterize "boundedness" for measures?

Comment: What is "boundedness of a measure"? Do you want to know when a measure is Radon?

Comment: Can you formulate your question into a well posed question? I'm confused. Do you want a function space whose dual is your space of measures? Do you want to know the dual of the space of continuous integrable functions? (With a given norm, maybe the sum of the $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ norms.) If it comes naturally in some research context (as you mention in a comment), can you elaborate?

Comment: Voting to close until we get some idea of what the question means by "boundedness".

Comment: Note that on $\mathbf R$ Lebesgue measure, and your $\mu(f) = \sum_{n\in\mathbf Z}f(n)$, are *not* bounded measures in the traditional sense of [Bourbaki](http://books.google.com/books?id=4UVk-CCwnQ0C&pg=PA16).

Comment: Could you give us some examples of what you consider "unbounded" measures?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just came back from discussion with a colleague. I have given one example that is not "bounded", or with some growing tails.

Comment: Thanks Joonas Limavirta, I have added some motivations and one "unbounded" measure in my post. I hope this may clarify the things. :-)

Comment: Thanks Francois Ziegier for your reference. That's why I put quotations on the word -- bounded. It is not in the traditional sense.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean by "bounded" is that $\mu([-n,n]) = O(n)$?

Comment: Robert Israel, my convolution equation in my post is my real motivation for this question. Yours is also right. :-)

Comment: @Anand, you contradict yourself in the response to Roebert, in the second example you've provided, the measure of the interval is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Again, your question is not well defined in my opinion. 

For a start I would erase the letters b,n,d from your entire post, as if $f$ might be concentrated, and $\mu$ spread (but not contained inside any bounded set), your equation is true, and this is causing a major disagreement as you can see in the comments.


Furthermore, all the examples you've given us are of purely atomic measures, those are easily analysed by Fourier transform. This is also the case with measures which are a.c. (with some assumptions on the derivative) wrt Lebesgue as the convolution is essentially computable.

Comment: Asaf, by $O(n)$, I mean the order should be $n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ but not larger. The understanding of the notation might causes some confusions.

Comment: Thanks Asaf for your comments. The whole thing is about the growing tails of the measure. If the measure has a density, the condition will be that the density is a bounded function. If there are only atomic part at each integers, the weight should be bounded. How about a general characterization?

Comment: Asaf, I have updated my post to remove the misleading word boundedness. I hope it is more clear now. Thanks a lot for your effort! :)

Comment: Nik Weaver, I have tried to make clear what is "boundedness" in my post. I agree there are some confusions. You might also notice from my motivation that why I use this word. I have followed suggestions of Asaf to avoid using this word. A more precise phrase is "without growing tails". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks many people here for helping me clarify the problem. The problem was not well explained in the beginning. Now I think it is much clearer. Anyway, thanks for many discussions!

Comment: I have reformulated my problem. I wish this time the problem is clearer and it may interest more mathematicians. Thanks a lot if you can vote it for reopen.

Comment: So now the question is: For what measures $\mu$ does $\mu * f \in L^\infty$ hold, right?

Comment: ＠Dirk, right! The function $f$ is continuous and integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,\mathcal M)$ be a measurable space and let $\lambda$ be a complex measure on $(X,\mathcal M)$. The total variation $\vert \lambda\vert$ is a positive measure on $(X,\mathcal M)$ with a finite total variation, i.e. such that  $\vert \lambda\vert(X)<+\infty$.
We define
$$
\vert \lambda\vert(X)=\sup_{\substack{{\text{$E_k$ pairwise disjoint}}\\{\text{with union $E$, $E_k\in \mathcal M$}}}
}\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\vert\lambda(E_k)\vert.
$$
The mapping $\lambda\mapsto\vert \lambda\vert(X)$ is a norm on the vector space $\mathscr M(X,\mathcal M)$ of complex measures on $(X,\mathcal M)$ and make it a Banach space.
So what you call the space of bounded measures is $\mathscr M(X,\mathcal M)$.
A fact should be noted: a positive measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal M)$
is not always a complex measure in particular since $\mu(X)$ may be $+\infty$.

Regarding your question, you may require a somewhat stronger property which would be
$$
\hat \mu\hat f\in L^1(\mathbb R).\tag{$\sharp$}
$$ 
This implies $\mu\ast f\in L^\infty$ with a norm smaller than the $L^1$ norm of $\hat \mu\hat f$. However, you have to make sure  that the Fourier transform of $f$ makes sense as well as the product. For instance when $f(x)=e^{-\vert x\vert}$,
this would require
$$
\hat\mu(\xi)=(1+\xi^2) g(\xi),\quad\text{with $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$,}
$$
providing examples. A weaker requirement than $(\sharp)$ would be 
$$
\hat \mu\hat f\text{ is a bounded measure}.\tag{$\flat$}
$$ 
As noted in my comment below that would contain the case $f=e^{-\vert x\vert}$ and $\mu$ the Dirac comb.

Comment: Thanks Bazin for your answer. I am working on measures on $\mathbb{R}$. The examples that I give above all have infinite total mass.

Comment: I have added a complement to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Bazin for your help! It is a good idea to use the Fourier transform. Your condition is a bit too strong because the example $\mu=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta_n$ fails. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, $\hat \mu=\mu$ by Poisson summation formula. It is probably possible to weaken my requirement to $$\hat \mu\hat f\text{  is a measure with a finite total mass}.$$ If $f=e^{-\vert x\vert}$, you find $\hat f\hat \mu$ with finite mass since $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Bazin. Do you mean $\hat{\mu}\hat{f}$ is a measure on complex plain with finite total mass?

Comment: $\hat \mu\hat f$ should be a measure on the real line with finite total mass.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the Fourier transform gives in general complex functions. Did I miss something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17262/discussion-between-anand-and-bazin).

Comment: $\hat \mu\hat f$ is a complex (valued) measure on the real line with finite total mass.